# Subclass a class in Django to accept an additional kwarg

Tags: python, ajax, django, model, subclass

I am trying to subclass an ajax uploader to accept a hash_id of a django model (so that it may create the model upon the successful upload of an image) and am having trouble passing the additional kwarg (widget2_hash_id). I would appreciate guidance on how to properly add the kwarg.

views.py:

```
class S3UploadBackend_Widget2EditableImage(S3UploadBackend):

  def upload(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.widget2_hash_id = kwargs.pop('widget2_hash_id')

    k = Key(self._bucket)
    chunk = uploaded.read()
    k.set_contents_from_string(chunk)

    # create uploaded file
    fh = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    k.get_contents_to_file(fh)
    fh.seek(0)
    saveable_file = SimpleUploadedFile(k.name, fh.read())

    # delete aws key and close tempfile
    _media_bucket.delete_key(k)
    fh.close()

    self.widget2 = Widget2.objects.get(hash_id = self.widget2_hash_id)

    self.widget2_editable_image = Widget2EditableImage(image = saveable_file, widget2 = self.widget2)
    self.widget2_editable_image.save()

    if k.key:
      self.key = k.key
      return True
    else:
      # Key creation failed.
      return False

  def upload_complete(self, request, filename):
    # Manually add S3 key to ajaxuploader JSONresponse
    res =  {"aws_file_key": self.key, "url": self.widget2_editable_image.image.url}
```

views.py:

```
widget2_editable_image_ajax_uploader = AjaxFileUploader(backend=S3UploadBackend_Widget2EditableImage)
```

urls.py:

```
(r'^widget2/widget2_image_upload/(?P<widget2_hash_id>[a-fA-F0-9]+)/$', 'widget2.views.widget2_editable_image_ajax_uploader'),
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zain/XXX/lib/Django-1.3.1/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget2_hash_id'

[20/Aug/2012 20:50:44] "POST /widget2/widget2_image_upload/d9dc4fab3d5e0eb45995/?qqfile=s3Zas.jpg HTTP/1.1" 500 870358
```

EDIT: I tried this inside the class and get the same error:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  try:
    self.widget2 = Widget2.objects.get(hash_id = kwargs.pop('widget2_hash_id'))
  except KeyError:
    self.widget2_hash_id = None
  super(S3UploadBackend_Widget2EditableImage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

EDIT2: here is the AjaxFileUploader class:

```
class AjaxFileUploader(object):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    def __init__(self, backend=None, **kwargs):                           
        if backend is None:                                               
            backend = LocalUploadBackend                                  
        self.get_backend = lambda: backend(**kwargs)                      

    def __call__(self, request, **kwargs):                                
        return self._ajax_upload(request)                                 

    def _ajax_upload(self, request):                                      
        if request.method == "POST":                                      
            if request.is_ajax():                                         
                # the file is stored raw in the request                   
                upload = request                                          
                is_raw = True                                             
                # AJAX Upload will pass the filename in the querystring if it
                # is the "advanced" ajax upload                           
                try:                                                      
                    filename = request.GET['qqfile']                      

                except KeyError:                                          
                    return HttpResponseBadRequest("AJAX request not valid")
            # not an ajax upload, so it was the "basic" iframe version with
            # submission via form                                         
            else:                                                         
                is_raw = False                                            
                if len(request.FILES) == 1:                               
                    # FILES is a dictionary in Django but Ajax Upload gives
                    # the uploaded file an ID based on a random number, so it
                    # cannot be guessed here in the code. Rather than editing
                    # Ajax Upload to pass the ID in the querystring, observe
                    # that each upload is a separate request, so FILES should
                    # only have one entry. Thus, we can just grab the first
                    # (and only) value in the dict.                       
                    upload = request.FILES.values()[0]                    
                else:                                                     
                    raise Http404("Bad Upload")                           
                filename = upload.name                                    

            backend = self.get_backend()                                  

            # custom filename handler                                     
            # Override filename to avoid collisons                        
            filename = unicode(hashlib.sha1(str(datetime.datetime.now())).hexdigest()[0:6]) + filename
            filename = (backend.update_filename(request, filename)        
                        or filename)                                      

            # save the file                                               
            backend.setup(filename)                                       
            success = backend.upload(upload, filename, is_raw)            

            # callback                                                    
            extra_context = backend.upload_complete(request, filename)    

            # let Ajax Upload know whether we saved it or not             
            ret_json = {'success': success, 'filename': filename}         
            if extra_context is not None:                                 
                ret_json.update(extra_context)                            

              return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ret_json, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder))
```

Comment: Seems like the class that's being called from the url is `AjaxFileUploader`, and that's the one that's getting the unexpected kwarg. Can you post the source to that class?

Comment: @DanielRoseman posted! Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: @zallarak I updated my answer in response to your deleted comment. What I meant was that you weren't using the extra arg in the the view code. It's the view that gets the parameter and it's the view's job to pass it to the backend. I found out where you were missing the parameter. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Just accept the additional parameter, pass it to your _ajax_upload method and pass it down to the backend as I described in my answer. Your view should not subclass the storage backend, they are unrelated objects. You should also modify your get_backend method so that it returns the right backend.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco, I modified __call__ and now get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zain/XXX/lib/Django-1.3.1/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget2_hash_id'

Comment: @zallarak Are you sure that the view code posted is exact? (especially the **kwargs bit in AjaxUploader)

Comment: @ThomasOrozco thanks I figured it out, my code was a little messy, I have a slight headache today haha.. thanks so much, I learned a lot from your post and it helped me fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The explanation

In  your `urls.py`, you have this:

```
(r'^widget2/widget2_image_upload/(?P<widget2_hash_id>[a-fA-F0-9]+)/$', 'widget2.views.widget2_editable_image_ajax_uploader'),
```

When this `url` gets matched, `django` will dispatch the request, as well as the args to the given view, so, if we break it down, the following arguments will be passed to `widget2.views.widget2_editable_image_ajax_uploader` (the `view`):

```
request
*args: []
*kwargs: {'widget2_hash_id':'somehashid',}
```

Now, what does `dispatch` mean in `django` vocabulary? Well, basically, it means call function.

It so happens that `widget2.views.widget2_editable_image_ajax_uploader` has a call method, so `django` will happily call this method with the arguments mentionned above.

Unfortunately, as your view does not accept the `widget2_hash_id` kwarg, python is going to raise an error. Which it does.

I think that the point were you got lost is that you missed the fact that it's the view that gets passed the extra arg, not the backend. It's then the view's job to pass it down to the backend.

### The solutions

#### The easy one

You just need to modify your `__call__` method so that it accepts the additional arg, and then passes it on to the `_ajax_upload` method.

Then, you need to pass the argument to your backend. To this end, you should change the following line:

```
backend.upload(upload, filename, is_raw)
```

to

```
backend.upload(upload, filename, is_raw, widget2_hash_id)
```

#### The right one

Now, I must say that I'm a bit confused as to what you are doing. You seem to be using objects as views, but then, why wouldn't you use `django`'s awesome [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/)?

The documentation used to be pretty lacking (I honestly can't tell if that's still the case), so here's [a small guide to get you started](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2011/12/29/class-based-views-django-13/).

Take some time to study and use them. They are very easy to use and extend, and they will save you a huge amount of time in the long run.

### On a closing note

Please do use [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/), because they rock.